# Dynamic DHCP server assignment on batman-adv mesh network

Tags: embedded-linux, dhcp, mesh-network

I'm looking to set up distributed mesh network using the batman-adv Linux kernel module. However, I don't want to have to statically assign IP addresses to all my nodes therefore my first thought was to use DHCP. The problem arises in my scenario that any node could come and go in the mesh network as they move in and out range of the network. Therefore manually allocating a single or even a few DHCP servers isn't realistic as that DHCP server may drop out of the network at anytime. Is there a dynamic way to reassign the DHCP server based on the nodes still within the network when the previous DHCP server drops from the network?